# Put file's content in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file which I need to store in a list.

**FILE:**

```
1 1
4 2
9 10
```

I would like to have a list of objects.
`L = [obj obj obj]`

**CODE:**

```
def putInList(pathToFile):
     myList = []
     with open(pathToFile) as f:
         for line in f:
             s = line.split()
             x, y = [int(v) for v in s]
             jemand = Mensch(x, y)
             myList.append(jemand)
     return myList
```

This works fine!
My problem is that I access **DISK MEMORY** the number of lines times!

And this sample is artificial I will be working with much bigger files. So I wrote a slicer that puts them into `~100MB` `.txt` files. So I would like to put them in a `list` without accessing the `disk memory` million of times.

After search and other questions on StackOverFlow I found this piece of code:

```
a = open(fileToPath, 'r')
L = [line for line in a.readlines()]
```

But I have no clue to how to parse a list ?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, you will not access disk memory $lines times. Buffering deals with that. Don't worry, I've iterated through files that were several gigabytes large.

Comment: @L3viathan, Only Parsing a 100MB file takes that way 15 minutes! Does it sound normal ?

Comment: I don't know what your `Mensch` class does, so I don't know exactly what the bottleneck is. But splitting the file up in parts doesn't help if you put everything in your RAM in the end anyways. For more suggestions see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, you will not access disk memory $lines times. Buffering deals with that.

I can make a few recommendations though. Your line splitting logic is more complicated than it needs to be. One way of making it (in my opinion) clearer, is doing:

```
x, y = map(int, line.split())
```

That way you don't needlessly create a list that is discarded immediately afterwards.

If you later iterate through `myList`, and only do it once, you can drop the list entirely, and use a generator function instead:

```
def putInList(pathToFile):
     with open(pathToFile) as f:
         for line in f:
             x, y = map(int, line.split())
             yield Mensch(x, y)
```

You can then iterate over it using `for mensch in putInList(filename):`, although you might want to rename the function in that case. If you still need a list, I would do that regardless and get the list using `myList = list(putInList(filename))`.

Comment: I am not doing anything in mensch for now.. Just parsing and saving `100MB` file in a list of objects and its driving me crazy why its taking 15-20 minutes~.

Comment: For 10MB it went from 3 minutes down to 2:30 so a small speedup. I will use now `map(int, line.split())`. But I just can't see anywhere how long should it take...

Comment: If you have on average two 2-digit numbers in a line, that's 6 bytes per line, meaning about 17 million objects — including the overhead for Python objects this is likely to translate to much more data in RAM. I wrote the simplest possible `Mensch` class fitting your spec, and an object takes 32 bytes in RAM. That's already way over 500 MB.

Answer (score 0):

`readLines()` [returns a list of the lines](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) in your text file by default. So, what I think you should do is:

```
def putInList(pathToFile):
    myList = []
    fileHandle = open(pathToFile, "r")
    lines = fileHandle.readLines()
    for line in lines:
        values = line.split()
        x, y = [int(v) for v in values]
        jemand = Mensch(x, y)
        myList.append(jemand)
    return myList
```